# how do i create post values as a session array?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

How do I create post values as a session array passing session to another pages? I'm working on a code it is showing only `Array` on the other pages when i echo `$_SESSSION['size'];`?

**Here My Both Functions:**

```
 $size = array('size');
 $_POST['size']; 
 $_SESSION['size'] = array();
 foreach ($size as $key)
 {
     if (isset($_POST[$key]))
     {
         $_SESSION['size'][$key] = $_POST[$key];
     }
 }


$size=$_POST['size'];
$max= count($_POST['size']);
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
{
    $_SESSION['size']= $_POST['size'];
}
```

**Both Function Are Showing Only `Array` On The Other Pages...**

Comment: What is the point of your last  `for` loop ?

Comment: You might want to clarify what your POST looks like and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 2):

When you `echo $_SESSION['size']` it will show `Array` because its an array, not single value.
If you want to check values, use this construction:

```
foreach($_SESSION['size'] as $key=>$val) {
    echo $key . '=>' . $val . '<br />';
}
```

Instead of

echo $_SESSION['size'];

You can also use:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['size']);
```

or

```
print_r($_SESSION['size']);
```

Comment: kasyr now i'm using print_r($_SESSION['size']); on the other pages but i don't want show array values on the page...?

Comment: i don't want to echo or print size name on the other page ... but just send the size values to another page for other functions

Answer (score 0):

On the first page simply store the value(s):

```
$_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];
```

Now, if your POST contained only a single value for `size`, you simply use this:

```
echo $_POST['size'];

// or this:
some_function($_POST['size']);
```

However, if your POST really had an array of values for `size` (which is possible), you would also have an array in your session. You then need a simple loop:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['size'] as $size) {
  echo $size;

  // or this:
  some_function($size);
}
```

Combined code that handles both cases:

```
if (is_array($_SESSION['size'])) {
  foreach ($_SESSION['size'] as $size) {
    echo $size;

    // or this:
    some_function($size);
  }
} else {
  echo $_SESSION['size'];

  // or this:
  some_function($_SESSION['size']);
}
```